# How to access JSON object after 3rd party upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How do I get at the JSON object after a successful upload as described here? https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails#accessing-filepicker-file-with-onchange

I am able to upload the file successfully and a JSON object is supposedly returned. How do I parse this JSON object into my rails app?

Comment: What are the params received by your Rails app after the upload? Can you post it please?

Comment: Note that [the section of the document you linked](https://github.com/Ink/filepicker-rails#accessing-filepicker-file-with-onchange) talks about JSON given to the *JavaScript* on the page, not to the Rails app. It says that whatever JavaScript handler `function(event) { ... }` you have for the `onchange` event can access the array of JSON in `event.fpfiles`. If you want that exact JSON on the server, you could send it with AJAX, but there's probably an easier way to get that data by looking at the files that were actually uploaded (perhaps with the filepicker.io API).

Comment: @Rory I can't find anything in the API's to get the name of the file uploaded to S3. How would I send it with AJAX?

Comment: @MrYoshjii The only params that my rails app gets is the "filepicker_url" which then goes into my User model after the form is submitted. The problem is that I need the S3 URL which is different. Trying to figure out how to get at it?